# Stopping Cloud Data Fusion Instance

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I have production pipelines which only runs for couple of hours using Google Data Fusion. I would like to stop the Data Fusion Instance and start it the next day. I don't see an option to stop the instance. Is there anyway we can stop the instance and start the same instance again ?

Answer (score 5):

As per design [Data Fusion](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs) instance is running in a GCP [tenancy](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/glossary#tenancy) unit that guarantees the user fully automated way to manage all the cloud resources and services (GKE cluster, Cloud Storage, Cloud SQL, Persistent Disk, Elasticsearch, and Cloud KMS, etc.) for storing, developing and executing customer pipelines. Therefore, there is **no possibility** to terminate Data Fusion instance, thus all the pipeline service execution contributors are launching on demand and clearing after pipeline completion, find [here](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/pricing) the price charging concepts.